# Memory Error When Attempting ec2 pip Install

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip, out-of-memory

I'm currently working on a t2.micro ec2 instance. I've pip installed quite a few things without issue as of now, but now I'm running into an error with

```
pip install autogluon
```

When attempting this, I hit a

`MemoryError`

I've also attempted

```
pip --no-cache-dir install autogluon
```

Which is then throwing the following error:

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

I've tried increasing the size of the ec2 instance but still run into the same error. I've also tried setting a tmpdir like below:

```
TMPDIR=/folder/address/here/ pip install --cache-dir=/folder/address/here/ --build /folder/address/here/ autogluon
```

But again run into the same error. Is there something else to attempt that I'm missing to allow me to pip install the packages I need?